# How can I download a list of users from an LDAP server using Perl?

Tags: perl, ldap, wiki

I want to upload a list of users from my work's LDAP server to upload into our wiki as a company directory.
How can I download a list of users from an LDAP server using Perl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [NET::LDAP](http://ldap.perl.org/) module.

A little example from the [POD](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP.pod):

```
use Net::LDAP;

$ldap = Net::LDAP->new( 'ldap.bigfoot.com' ) or die "$@";

$mesg = $ldap->bind ;    # an anonymous bind

$mesg = $ldap->search( # perform a search
                       base   => "c=US",
                       filter => "(&(sn=Barr) (o=Texas Instruments))"
                     );
$mesg->code && die $mesg->error;

foreach $entry ($mesg->entries) { $entry->dump; }

$mesg = $ldap->unbind;   # take down session
```

Comment: what parameter should I put on the $ldap->search() to get all the users in the server?

Comment: that depends solely on the configuration of your server.

Comment: I am having some problems with code based on the example above. It looked like it was working but I realized my bind logon is failing. Then it defaults to anonymous. Is there a debug variable one can use to make sure its logging in?